# Influence of Habilitation's field of study on the Professorship

Tags: postdocs, germany, physics, habilitation

Suppose person X did Bachelors, Masters, PhD, and postdoc in Physics. Then, X wants to start a Habilitation. Although the work will be relevant to Physics, the supervising professor is officially a computer science/mathematics professor, and therefore, the Habilitation will (officially) not be in Physics.

I want to know how does this affect the X's career in terms of
(1) becoming a professor
(2) going to industry

Comment: Does habilitation have any use/value outside academia? (Not snark, a question.)

Comment: Habilitation is simply a certified licence to teach. So, no. But semi-leading a group can count as experience.

Comment: Are there several meanings of the word? I normally assume it is like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Habilitation. That is, a higher degree than a doctorate enabling a full professorship, not a license to teach.

Comment: It is the same: you are conferred "facultas docendi". Since last 2 decades it is not the only route to Professorship in Germany.

Comment: @quantum In Germany, you don't need habilitation to become a professor so it is not a requirement. I would, therefore, assume that it does not matter from which faculty you obtain it (Btw. nothing to do with the supervising professor but the faculty issuing the certificate).

Comment: In France, it's a habilitation to direct research, and in particular supervise young researchers including graduate students, and is often necessary to move up academic ranks.

Comment: Is there even such a concept (officially!) as a "supervising professor"? (Of course, you need teaching experience to get your habilitation, and those lectures must be officially supervised by a professor, but I don't even think it always has to be the same professor.)

Comment: @user151413 Not a supervisor but a reviewer

Comment: @Younes A reviewer is - I guess - yet again sth. different: For a Habilitation, you need to get reviews (typically also external). *But* you also need to demonstrate teaching experience, and since w/out a Habilitation, you are not allowed to teach independently (e.g., you are not allowed to take exams), someone has to take responsibility for your lectures, which is some kind of "supervisory" role.

Comment: @user151413 I would not call him/her a supervisor. You can be hired in Landstelle/Haushaltsstelle (as a teaching position) without habilitation and you will be responsible for everything. Of course responsible for the course will have an eye on you during the semester but he won't testify anything for your habilitation. I think the evaluation of the students will be much more important.

Comment: @Younes I agree I would not call them a supervisor. But also not reviewer -- that sounds like the person who has to write a (scientific or didactic) report for the habilitation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field of habilitation will, with all likelihood, not affect the chances to become a professor, and certainly not anything related to going to industry.

In fact, a habilitation is not even needed to become a professor, and in particular in physics and related fields, almost no-one pays attention to it.

(It is of course conceivable that the lack of a habilitation might be used as an argument against a candidate in a committee if someone wants to push for another candidate, but it would be seen as a very weak argument (if at all), and even less so if it were a habilitation in a different field.)

On the other hand, where the field of the habilitation *does* matter is in exactly what the habilitation is for: To give you the right to independently teach lectures, and to independently supervise PhD students and act as the official supervisor. If your habilitation is, say, in chemistry, this will a priori only give you the venia legendi in that field: Thus, if you want to teach/supervise/... at the physics department, this might be difficult. (Not sure about the formal implications.) Similarly, if you would move to a different university and would like to move your habilitation (so you could call yourself *Privatdozent*), this would most likely again have to be in the field of the habilitation.